# How do I delete a particular node of an XML column in sql server 2008 R2 whose sub node matches a given criteria

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

```
<VirAddresses>
    <VirAddress>
        <VirAddKey>0</VirAddKey>
        <VirAddressLine>abc@gmail.com</VirAddressLine>
        <Bounced>false</Bounced>
        <Functions>
            <Function>E-mail</Function>
        </Functions>
    </VirAddress>
    <VirAddress>
        <VirAddKey>1</VirAddKey>
        <VirAddressLine>0123456789</VirAddressLine>
        <Bounced>false</Bounced>
        <Functions>
            <Function>Mobile</Function>
        </Functions>
    </VirAddress>
</VirAddresses>
```

My end goal is to modify the XML column, `IF the Function=E-mail then` need to delete this particular VirAddress node among multiple VirAddress nodes
 under VirAddresses.
The position of VirAddress `(where Function=E-mail)` is not fixed in XML, like above sample having VirAddress `(where Function=E-mail)` at first 
position but it may vary in other xml.

I have tried query like this :

```
UPDATE MyTable  
SET xmlCol.modify('delete(/VirAddresses/VirAddress/Functions[Function="E-mail"]/../../VirAddress)') 
where ID in (347,349) and 
xmlCol.exist('/VirAddresses/VirAddress/Functions[Function="E-mail"]') = 1
```

But above query removed all VirAddress nodes under VirAddresses node.

I  have been at this for several hours to no avail. Help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the xquery like this;

```
UPDATE MyTable  
SET xmlCol.modify('delete //VirAddress[Functions/Function="E-mail"]')
where ID in (347,349) and 
xmlCol.exist('//VirAddress[Functions/Function="E-mail"]') = 1
```

Rather than finding the Function node and going back, just find the VirAddress node that contains the Function node.